# How can I use upsert in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I directly convert the data from postgresql to json and transfer it to mongo.

```
sql= """select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(a))) from(select * from {}) a ;  """.format(row[0])
            cursor.execute(sql_etl)
            data = cursor.fetchall()
            data=data[0][0]
if isinstance(data, list):
    collection.insert_many(data,upsert=True)
    
else:
    collection.insert_one(data)
```

I am using insert_many for this. But I get duplicate with insert_many.
Pymongo also had upsert for duplicate. Used in the update_many function. How can I use this upsert in update_many?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bulk_write` to perform multiple write operation.

And `ReplaceOne` to have "upsert" queries

```
from pymongo import ReplaceOne

upserts = [ReplaceOne({"_id": x["_id"]}, x, upsert=True) for x in data]
collecion.bulk_write(upserts, ordered=True)
```

Comment: thanks. but x ['id'] was giving an error. I did that too>>[ReplaceOne({"_id": next(iter(x.values()))}, x, upsert=True) for x in data]. But now the id I pulled from postgresql is the same as the '_id' I put to mongodb?

Comment: Yes by doing that iit will be the id as in postgresql. I was using `_id` in my example, but you can use any field that mongo query to find if it's an insert or an update.